# How to view user spending on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Is there any way to view dollars and resources spent for individual users managed through the Amazon IAM service?

I'm tasked with administering sub-accounts on behalf of an owner of an AWS account. The sub-accounts have permissions to launch EC2 instances. It's my job to make sure they don't spend too many resources on our account, but I can not find the breakdown of dollars spent by users anywhere.

How to get this information?

Comment: Some information here (from 2011): http://blog.bitnami.com/2011/12/monitor-your-estimated-aws-charges-with.html. Maybe the problem is that we need Premium Support in order to see this information? I'm surprised that the information is so hard to find...

Comment: It seems CloudWatch has an ability (Billing alarm) which almost covers this issue. Not quite what I want, as I'm interested in monitoring individual users, not the overall spending. Also, you have to create the Alarm in N.Virginia (US East), but it should draw data from all regions.

Comment: You should use tags with user=name

Comment: Yes, I've instructed the users to tag their instances. Of course that approach is a little fragile, as they have to remember to do it.

Comment: Also that still does not solve the problem of getting a run-down of dollars spent per user.

Comment: AWS billing is not broken down by users (as you may already know).  If you don't have much users, then having separate accounts would work best.  Also, using tags are fragile, but the following AWS blog came out just today:  http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/07/08/announcing-resource-permissions-for-amazon-ec2-and-amazon-rds/?ref_=pe_395470_31013550_7  -- not sure if that will help reinforce the tag requirement.

Comment: A link from that blog also looks useful: (get your bill) http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/about/getbill.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [the IAM FAQ](http://aws.amazon.com/iam/faqs/#Will_AWS_Billing_provide_aggregated_usage_and_cost_breakdowns_by_user):

```
Q: Will AWS Billing provide aggregated usage and cost breakdowns by user?
A: Not initially. This is planned for a future release.
```

Future, yeah.  You might be able to tease it out with [Programmatic AWS Billing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/about/programaccess.html).  I don't use IAM right now, but I do have PAB enabled.  Here are the fields present in my CSV:

*InvoiceID,PayerAccountId,LinkedAccountId,RecordType,RecordID,BillingPeriodStartDate,BillingPeriodEndDate,InvoiceDate,PayerAccountName,LinkedAccountName,TaxationAddress,PayerPONumber,ProductCode,ProductName,SellerOfRecord,UsageType,Operation,RateId,ItemDescription,UsageStartDate,UsageEndDate,UsageQuantity,BlendedRate,CurrencyCode,CostBeforeTax,Credits,TaxAmount,TaxType,TotalCost*

We use separate accounts + [Consolidated Billing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/about/consolidatedbilling.html) + Activity by Account for this exact purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Programmatic Billing Access files don't break it down to the IAM user level but you can use tagging to get a similar results.

Full disclosure, I work for Cloudability but we have a great tool to help with separating costs.

http://blog.cloudability.com/advanced-techniques-for-separating-organizing-your-aws-costs/